# Declare property name from string

Tags: javascript

I have this

```
oArray = {};
aProperty = "Property1";
aValue = "Value1";
```

Is there any way I can use aProperty value as a object name in the array?  This is the desired result:

```
oArray = {
  Property1: "Value1"
};
```

Thanks in advance and regards

Comment: Use `oArray = {[aProperty]: aValue}`. This is called a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

Comment: It worked, thanks a mil. The IDE was complaining about the syntax but in the end it executed without problems

Answer (score 4):

It is as simple as below.

```js
var oArray = {};
var aProperty = "Property1";
var aValue = "Value1";

oArray[aProperty] = aValue;
console.log(oArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes like this:

```js
aProperty = "Property1";
aValue = "Value1";
oArray = {[aProperty]: aValue};
```